# Estilo tabs con css

Tags: html, css, css3

```
<div class="tab-system">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'LogosSubidos')">Uploaded Logos</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'LogosDescargados')">Downloaded Logos</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'LogosVotados')">Voted Logos</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'EditProfile')">Edit Profile</button>
</div>
```

Tengo estos tabs creados, y cuando esta activo uno tiene un pequeño border con puntas redondeadas arriba y abajo el .tab-system tiene un border que ocupa todo el width

```
/* Style the tab */
.tab-system {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #535353;
}

.tab-system button {
    background-color: inherit;               
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #535353;
}
.tab-system button:hover,.tab-system button.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#535353;
    border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #535353;
    border-left:1px solid  #535353;
    border-right: 1px solid #535353;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}


/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
</style>
```

La pregunta es: Cuando tengo seleccionado el primer tab por ejemplo como pueo hacer para que el border inferior del .tab-system de ese cacho no se vea, como la imagen que os pongo a continuacion donde el escogido es active y el border inferrior no se ve y en los demas si

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría con el pseudoelemento `:after`, asignándole dimensiones y con posicionamiento relativo para «subirlo» ese píxel que no se logra fácilmente con el método del borde en el contenedor. Por último, un z-index inferior para tener en «por encima» el estilo que aplicamos a los botones. Esta idea puede ser mejorada, pero considero que se entiende el concepto.

```css
.tab-system {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #535353;*/
}

.tab-system:after {
  background-color: black;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab-system button {
    background-color: inherit;               
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #535353;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid  #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab-system button:hover,.tab-system button.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#535353;
    border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #535353;
    border-left:1px solid  #535353;
    border-right: 1px solid #535353;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-system">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'LogosSubidos')">Uploaded Logos</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'LogosDescargados')">Downloaded Logos</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'LogosVotados')">Voted Logos</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'EditProfile')">Edit Profile</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

la clase active no debe tener el border-bottom que le has puesto. 
Es decir:

Despues de:

```
.tab-system button:hover,.tab-system button.active {...}
```

Tienes que poner esto:

```
.tab-system button.active {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero aun poniendo border-bottom:0px !important; se sigue viendo el border del container en ese trozo

Comment: @Caldeiro prueba a quitar !important de la regla de CSS aplicada para ambos.

Comment: Tampoco me funciona se sigue viendo ..